# Formatting options for prettyCheckboxGroup are not applied when using updatePrettyCheckboxGroup

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

I am writing a Shiny app where the `prettyCheckboxGroup` choices are populated by a user-uploaded .csv file. If I manually set the `choices` (e.g. "A", "B", "C"), then I can change `status`, `shape`, `outline`, etc. However, if I use `updatePrettyCheckboxGroup` based on an `observeEvent` in my server code, then the result is just the default style.

```
ui <- navbarPage("Tabbed page",
                 tabPanel("Works",
                          prettyCheckboxGroup(
                            inputId = "Id001",
                            label = "Checkboxes with status",
                            choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
                            inline = TRUE,
                            status = "danger",
                            shape = "round"),

                 ),
                 tabPanel("Doesn't Work",
                          fileInput("Line_Dataset", label = "Choose Data"),                    
                          prettyCheckboxGroup(
                            inputId = "Broken",
                            label = "Checkboxes with status", 
                            choices = NULL,
                            inline = TRUE,
                            status = "danger",
                            shape = "round"),
                 )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  LineFile <- eventReactive(c(input$Line_Dataset), {
    read_csv(input$Line_Dataset$datapath, col_names = T)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Line_Dataset,
               {elements_line_data <- LineFile() %>%
                 colnames()
               
               updatePrettyCheckboxGroup(session,
                                         "Broken",
                                         choices = elements_line_data)
               })
  
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Where should I put the `status` and `shape` arguments when using updatePrettyCheckboxGroup? Do they need to go in the server file?

Note, I get the same results when trying to use `awesomeCheckboxGroup` and `update...` but I chose to use pretty because of the number of formatting options.

Thanks,
Jeremy

P.S. I apologise for not providing a .csv but any file will work

EDIT: Screenshots of the issue. I would like the Checkbox buttons in the "Doesn't work" tab to look the same as those in "Works".
[image]

Comment: Adding `inline = TRUE` in `updatePrettyCheckboxGroup` should fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `updatePrettyCheckbox()` lacks the possibility to pass the arguments status and shape, so the only option to generate the correct checkbox is directly using `renderUI()`. Anyways, the problem was that because those two arguments weren't present when `updatePrettyCheckbox()` was called, a default format was re-rendered.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- navbarPage("Tabbed page",
                 tabPanel("Works",
                          prettyCheckboxGroup(
                              inputId = "Id001",
                              label = "Checkboxes with status",
                              choices = c("A", "B", "C"),
                              inline = TRUE,
                              status = "danger",
                              shape = "round")
                          
                 ),
                 tabPanel("Doesn't Work",
                          fileInput("Line_Dataset", label = "Choose Data"),
                 uiOutput('download_with_prettychbx')
                 )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    LineFile <- eventReactive(c(input$Line_Dataset), {
        read_csv(input$Line_Dataset$datapath, col_names = T,)
        
    })
    
    
    
    observeEvent(input$Line_Dataset, {
    
        elements_line_data <- LineFile() %>%
            colnames()

    output$download_with_prettychbx <- renderUI({
    tagList(
                        
    prettyCheckboxGroup(
        inputId = "Broken",
        label = "Checkboxes with status", 
        choices = LineFile(),
        inline = TRUE,
        status = "danger",
        shape = "round")
    )
              
                 })})
    
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately this isn't working for me. I copied your code into R but when I loaded a .csv it was either in the default format again or I received an error: "All sub-lists in "choices" must be named [No stack trace available]". I have added screenshots to my question to demonstrate.

Comment: I fixed the answer . Turns out that using reactive inside observeEvent was redundant. The issue was with `updatePrettyCheckbox()`.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. And thank you for the explanation because I'm still learning shiny and everything I have learned so far tells me `prettyCheckboxGroup` only goes in the ui code. Out of curiosity, why did you put it all inside a `tagList`? I was able to run it without, I think because of the { }, so I was wondering if creating an HTML tag had some added benefit or functionality.